# Customize query not working in Wordpress page?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

This is page of wordpress I am adding core php code for displaying data into table as per select input for that I am using javascript for gettin input and pass to the page page.And that page getting value as per value fir a mysql query.But my core php code dispaly as it is on screen. I am not able to understand how to do this. Beacuse I am new in wordpress Today is my first day in wordpress. Please help me ..Thanks in advance

```
    <?php
            $var=$_COOKIE['v'];
        $id = explode(",", $var);
            echo 'hawno:'.$id[1];
           $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $db = mysql_select_db("shepherddb");
    $err = error_reporting(E_ALL && ~E_NOTICE);
    $result=mysql_query("select              ship_id,track_id,track_ship_id,track_mod_of_transport,track_location,track_status from 
tracking,shipment");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        print_r($data);
}   
    ?>
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Not error but mysql query print as it is on screen..I will attach screen shot

Comment: add quotes in get_results("YOUR_QUERY");

Comment: no same thing print as it is on screen as text

Comment: use php mysqli or PDO connection instead of WP.

Comment: can you give me example

Comment: $result=mysql_query("select                      ship_id,track_id,track_ship_id,track_mod_of_transport,track_location,track_status from 
tracking,shipment");..can I use like this

Comment: yes you can use. I will provide you sample code.

Comment: check this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: problem in your query. Please  use like this  `SELECT table1.column_name, table2.column_name
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;`

Comment: Your Wp Databas and custom database is same ?

Comment: No it's not working I am write very simple query select track_id.... from tracking..After that I am not able to understand is result is coming or not how to display result of fire query

Comment: In while loop I have write a code like .. echo"hello";
echo'<tr><td>'.$data['track_id'].'</td></tr>'; but there error is ';} print on screen

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $wpdb global object provided by wordpress.

For example ,

```
global $wpdb;
```

$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = 1', OBJECT );

You can also use pre_get_posts action to modify the POSTS Query.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'your_theme_function' );
```

Let me know if you need more information on the same.

Comment: where this line add can you update ans .....add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'your_theme_function' );

Comment: I have add as per u mention but print as it is query of page..but I can't understand this line add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'your_theme_function' ); exactly where added this one

Comment: add this line with your built in function

For example : 

function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'movie' ) );
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');